# What does generic type X is (<>); mean?

Tags: ada

just what the title asks. I am trawling through some Ada code & came across

```ada
generic type X is (<>);
```

What does it mean? Is it something like a C++ template parameter?

Comment: You might want to take look at the section on [Generics](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/generics.html) from the online course [Introduction to Ada](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/index.html). A nice overview of all possible generic formal types can be found in the [appendix](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/appendices.html#appendix-a-generic-formal-types) of the course.

Comment: You can also take a look at the [Wikibook generic chapter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Generics)

Answer (score 6):

A generic in Ada is either a `package`, `procedure` or `function`,
with one or more formal parameters. A formal parameter can be an object, a type, a package or a subprogram. When instantiating a generic, you have to provide actuals for all the formal parameters.

```ada
generic
   type X is (<>); -- formal parameter
procedure Foo(Item : in X);
```

In this declaration `Foo` is the generic, and `X` is a formal parameter. The `(<>)` means that when you instantiate `Foo`, the actual for `X` must be of a discrete type (a signed integer type, a modular type, or an enumeration type):

```ada
procedure Bar is new Foo(Character);
```

Bar is now an instance of the generic procedure `Foo`, and can be called with a parameter of type `Character`:

```ada
Bar('@');
```